# API access security in salesforce

Tags: rest-api, api, security, schedulebatch, security-token

I have batch class which fetch data from API url & insert that data into salesforce. Our other team which is working on API from other side they need to set security so that only our saleforce login can access their API. when i send them a request to fetch data using API URL they need to check to see if it is coming from an approved source. How can we achieve this? can anyone please help us to do this.

Comment: No idea what you mean, can you rephrase question?

Comment: please check once again.

Comment: Still no information what endpoint is. If other system is not salesforce then question in my opinion is invalid as it is not our decision how external system will handle salesforce call. If other system is salesfroce question is invalid as there is no information about type of integration.(SF-to-SF, webService)...

Comment: Yes you are right. But from our side i mean in salesforce is anything which decide login access to salesforce. Is it security tokan?

Comment: Check if this will answer your doubts:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_loginrestrict.htm

Comment: We need to send user name with every request. Can you help me to send user name with every http request.

Comment: No I can't. No idea what you sent. Anyway it is up to you guys how you will define call. I think it is not possible to help you remotely.